# Segmented disable?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, segmentedcontrol

I'm configuring my UI, in my first view all work perfect, but on my second view have a problem with segment button.

[image]

And don't apear on my view. I can drag but still looks "disable" and generate warning `"Position is ambiguous for segmented control"`

What happen?

Comment: Someone? I just need configure this segment control to finish my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may solve your issue. Check the option "installed" in IB. see below gif image

[image]

Comment: Perfect, i had check installed on wR hC but not for all sizes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to select "Favs" controller in your storyboard, then select "Editor -> Resolve Autolayout Issues -> Reset to suggested constraints" from Xcode upper menu.